# sql get sum of sequece relations

Tags: sql

[image: enter link description here]

This is table account  and for each account may be  there is a relation to another account  as shown in first table.

I want to get the result shown in the second table which is as following:

For each account get sum of debit for  all related accounts (like sequence or recursive SQL).

[image]

Comment: 1. Which DBMS? 2. Say again why the sum of all elements under `id=1` is 85, i.e. does not include its own value whereas all the other sums include the debit stored on the record?

Comment: @HasanDhainy . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You can calculate that with do while or recursive operation

Comment: i added another description of what i exactly want , its like a tree calculation which calculate the sum of each branch's